# What triggers notifications of the form "Bell in session Shell" in KDE?

Tags: shell, kde, konsole, bell

I'm running KDE on Debian Testing.

From time to time, programs running in a terminal (Konsole) trigger system notifications of the form "Bell in session Shell".

**What triggers these notifications?**

Note: I'm not asking how to disable them - I know there's an option to do so in Konsole -> Settings -> Configure Notifications. I'm asking what behaviour triggers them in the first place, with a view of possibly modifying some of the programs that trigger them to not trigger them, or to trigger them under different conditions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is how konsole terminal emulator interprets bells.

Try to run in bash

```
sleep 3 && echo -e "\a"
```

Then switch to another app and wait 3 seconds.

Many many years ago when real terminals were connected to big computers, there was a special protocol called "escape sequences" to send commands to such terminals. There are sequences to change color, move to new line, or ring bell. First terminals were equipped with real bells to notify operator about some long-running task is ended.

Any modern terminal emulator (konsole, xterm, or real console when your are in text mode) simply emulates such terminal hence understands such sequences.

The `TERM` env. variable tells the name of emulated terminal. Some libs like `ncurses` then use `termcap` (or `terminfo`) file to find which sequence is used for what on this terminal.

Comment: I tried this, but `echo -e "\a"` does not produce the notification.

Comment: It does not work when your terminal is active. Try ``sleep 3 && echo -e "\a"``, then switch to another app, and wait 3 seconds.

Comment: Yep, that does it, thanks! So, if I understand correctly, the behaviour that triggers this notification is any program running in the terminal sending the character '\a' (ASCII code 7) to standard output/error?

Comment: Yes) But it may do it not directly, but using ``beep`` command from ``ncurses`` lib. Ncurses then reads ``termcap`` to find appropriate sequence for your termnial (konsole). This sequence is "\a". But some other terminal may have some different sequence.

Comment: Thanks! I found the line in the source code of the program I was running that was doing the beep (it was doing `fprintf(stderr, "\07")`) and got rid of it. Things are much more peaceful now :)

Comment: Why does it trigger the notification only if the terminal is not focused? I would understand it if, when focused, it made an actual sound, but it doesn't. So the effect of the "bell" signal is: if the terminal is inactive, notification, if it's active, nothing. That seems kind of backwards